# Error 0x80070002 - WindowsUpdateClient constantly downloads WinStore apps updates and fails to install them

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-store

According to **System Event Log**:

- WindowsUpdateClient constantly (multiple times per day) downloading WinStore 
  apps updates (Microsoft.BingWeather, Microsoft.BingNews, ...)
- trying to install them
- fails to install them (error: 0x80073CF1)

Why this is happening?

How can I heal or stop this?

---

**UPDATE:**

I added exclusion for WSHost.exe in Kaspersky. Something changed. Now I have another error code in the Event Log: 0x80070002

Comment: Error 0x80073CF1 is "Package Not Found". Do you perhaps have an antimalware program that is scanning downloads and immediately deleting them?

Comment: Right now I have running: Malwarebytes and Kaspersky Antivirus. Should I tweak their settings?

Comment: I would certainly start by looking at their settings. Since I don't use either of those products, nor do I download from the Windows Store, I can't give you specific advice.

Comment: @ Jeff Zeitlin, thanks for advice. I added exclusion for WSHost.exe in Kaspersky. Something changed. Now I have another error code in the Event Log: 0x80070002

Comment: 0x80070002: The system cannot find the file specified.